# Using the chrome cube explorer

Tags: javascript

I was looking for some people who have used Chrome's Cube Explorer http://iamthecu.be/.  The basic source code found on Rubik's official site, https://rubiks.com/chrome-cube-lab.  I want to program an automatic solver for this platform, but I'm not exactly sure how to get the code I have written to run.

Here is the file where I put my code before I modified anything.  The main point of emphasis is the block comment and the `ERNO.Solver = function() {...` sections:

```
    /*


    SOLVERS

    Our Cube has its own animation loop conveniently called Cube.loop().
    If Cube.isSolving === true then within that loop Cube will call
    window.solver.consider( cube ). This means when you create your own
    Solver instance you have to set window.solver equal to your instance.

    Solver.consider() will do some very basic checking and if all's well
    will pass the Cube instance to Solver.logic() which is the function that
    you need to write yourself. 

    Your logic() should return false is the cube is solved or if something's
    gone horribly wrong. This will set Cube.isSolving = false and stop the
    solver from being called within the Cube's animation loop. 

    Your logic() should return true if an incremental improvement has been 
    made and the logic() should be run again in the next loop; For example,
    run again after a twist queue completes.

    --

    @author Mark Lundin - http://www.mark-lundin.com
    @author Stewart Smith


*/








ERNO.Solver = function(){


    //  When you create your own Solver this is the only function you need to build yourself.
    //  Having said that, it will probably be the most intense function like ... ever!
    //  Check out my example in /scripts/solvers/stewart.js to see how you might go about it.

    this.logic = function( cube ){ return false };;
}




//  This is the method called within Cube.loop() when Cube.isSolving === true.
//  It will call Solver.logic() which is the function you need to fill in.

ERNO.Solver.prototype.consider = function( cube ){


    //  Was our solver passed a valid Cube?
    //  Kind of important, eh?

    if( cube === undefined ){

        console.warn( 'A cube [Cube] argument must be specified for Solver.consider().' );
        return false;
    }
    else if( cube instanceof ERNO.Cube === false ){

        console.warn( 'The cube argument provided is not a valid Cube.' );
        return false;
    }


    //  If we're solving we should really make certain we aren't shuffling!
    //  Otherwise our logic will never actually run.
    //  The hook for this is in Cube.loop() so look there to see what's up.

    cube.isShuffling = false;


    //  If the cube is already solved then our job is done before it started.
    //  If not, we need to try solving it using our current solve method.

    if( cube.isSolved() ){

        ERNO.Solver.prototype.explain( 'I’ve found that the cube is already solved.' );
        return false;
    }
    else return this.logic( cube );
};




//  We should always hit at what the Solver wants to do next
//  so we can hault auto-solving and give the user a chance to 
//  figure out the next move for his/herself.

ERNO.Solver.prototype.hint = function( text ){

    console.log(

        '%c'+ text +'%c\n',
        'background-color: #EEE; color: #333', ''
    );
};


//  If hinting is text displayed *before* a move is made
//  then explaining is text displayed *after* a move is made.

ERNO.Solver.prototype.explain = function( text ){

    console.log(

        'Solver says: %c '+ text +' %c\n',
        'color: #080', ''
    );
};
```

I modified the `ERNO.Solver = function(){...` to look like the code below, as the comment suggested and as it is written in the example file, `stewart.js`, and I put in some test code to run.

```
window.solver = new Solver();
solver.logic = function( cube ){...
```

But to no avail, when I run the method `cube.solve()`, or set the flag `cube.isSolving == true`, my function doesn't seem to run.  The same story is true if I substitute the `stewart.js` script in place of my own.  It seems like the constructor, `window.solver = new Solver()`, is failing because `Solver()` isn't defined, but I'm not sure where it could be defined.  It is not a member of `cube`, `window`, or `ERNO`, which are all objects in this environment.

I haven't really been able to find a good resource for how I should set this up.

If anyone knows how to use this tool, or has a good resource that I could learn from, that would be great.  Thank-you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, after I gave up once.  It turns out I didn't understand how the ERNO class was structured or how it fit into the big picture.  In order for the built in functions to call the `Solver()` function, an instance of that object must be created and subsequently attached to the `window` object.  after that, the code runs perfectly out of the box.

Defining `Solver()`:

```
ERNO.Solver = function(){...
```

Creating an instance of `Solver()` and attaching it to the `window` object:

```
mySolver = new ERNO.Solver()
window.solver = mySolver
```

Then, by calling `cube.solve()`, which sets `cube.isSolving` to `true`, the `cube.loop()` function will call `window.solver()` which will run the code written in the `ERNO.Solver()` function definition!!  Yay!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to figure out the same thing with no success so far. As I understood, the solver.logic function that is found on stweart.js should replace the  ERNO.Solver function that is found on solvers.js. then on the main process a new solver should be created and attached to the window object with window.solver = new Solver(); . From there the method cube.solve() can be called but it dosen't seem to work am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, i should mention That the solver function seems to run but I have the following error : "solvers.js Line 90 Uncaught ReferenceError: UP is not defined(…)"

Comment: @LorenzoPirondini Did you figure it out? If not change UP to ERNO.UP

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try, i did not figure it out, I ended up creating a custom undo method UndoAll that undo all the move made in the game, including the initial shuffle

Answer (score 0):

The ERNO class is structured quite straightforwardly, without any constructor definitions.

> In order for the built-in functions to call the Solver() function, a
>   instance of that object must be created and subsequently attached to
>   the window object. after that, the code runs perfectly out of the box.

The solver function made by Mark Lundin is a bit incomplete, and the focus was more on the interface , and the turning process of the virtual cube. There can be a lot of memory intensive tasks , that can be appended to make a better solver.

The site [Rubik's Cube Explorer](http://iamthecu.be/) , is good for an introduction to the concept of the cube, and there is a  lot of improvements that can be made to , `Solver()`.